# Run-time method invocation on casting objects in java

Tags: java, casting

plz help me understand the mehtod invocation on line2 of the below snippet which invokes the bMethod() of Orange class even if the Orange object is casted to Fig type on line1

```
     interface a{public void aMethod();}
     interface b{public void bMethod();}
     interface c extends a,b{public void cMethod();}
    class Fig implements b{
     @Override
    public void bMethod() {
        System.out.println("Fig a");
    }
    }

    class Orange extends Fig implements c{

    @Override
    public void aMethod() {
        System.out.println("Orange a");
    }

    @Override
    public void bMethod(){
        System.out.println("Orange b");
    }

    @Override
    public void cMethod() {
        System.out.println("Orange c");     
    }

   }
    public class Q71 {
      public static void main(String...args){
     Fig e = (Fig)(new Orange()); //line 1  -- 
        e.bMethod();              //line 2--invokes Orange's bMethod()?
     }
   }
```

Plz help I cannot figure out the runtime method invocation with proper reason ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymorphism is at works here.

The variable 'e' is holding a reference to a child object 'Orange'. Orange has overridden 'bMethod()', hence for objects of type 'Orange', method is going to output 'Orange b'. When the call to bMethod() was invoked in line 2, it called the method of the object and output 'Orange b' instead of 'Fig a'.

In order to check, just comment the overridden 'bMethod()' in Orange class and it will call the method of the parent call printing 'Fig a'.

Comment: Hello Andrew, I know about run-time polymorphism but my exact doubt is that the Orange object is being casted to Fig object type so now we have a Fig object referenced by 'e' right? Does casting converts one object type to another ?.  I understand if Fig e  = new Orange() was the case it would be no problem invoking the Orange version of bMethod()

Comment: @Kamlesh Sharma: Typecasts don’t change the type of an object. They only change the type of the *reference* pointing to it. That’s the key point of the runtime polymorphism. If you had to know the exact type at compile-time, it wasn’t *runtime* polymorphism anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In Java it is quite simple, everything depends on how you create your instance, no matter how you call it.

Therefore when you create isntance `new Orange()`, it will always be instance of orange and it will use orange methods, no matter if you cast it or not.

This line `Fig e = (Fig)(new Orange());` has no difference to this `Fig e = new Orange();`